# how can i generate an image from the motion vectors given?

Tags: image-processing

I have x and y-direction motion vectors for an image in double format. I have tried to do it using imagesc but it isn't workingI want to convert it back to the image. how can I do that??

Comment: Can provide more detail, what type of output image do you need?

Answer (score 1):

you can produce vector field by `quiver` function in MATLAB.